# Convex function exercise

Tags: convex-analysis

having a bit of trouble with this exercise;

Let f be a function, convex on $\mathbb{I}$, by writing $\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\lambda_k $ for $ n \ge  3 $ under the form $x_n\lambda_n+(1-\lambda_n)y_n$ with $y_n$ expressed with $x_k,  k\in [|1,n|] $ and $ \lambda_q, q\in[|1,n|]$ and $\lambda_i\in]0,1[$and $\sum_{n}^{i=1}\lambda_i =  1$ .
Prove that : 
$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_kf(x_k)\ge f(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\lambda_k)$.

The previous question was to demonstrate that ; 
$z\in ]x,y[ <=> \exists\lambda, z=x\lambda + (1-\lambda)y$

Comment: May be n dimensional Jensen's inequality may fit the bill?

Comment: This needs rewriting. It is strangely confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_ix_i=$$

$$\lambda_nx_n+(1-\lambda_n)\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{\lambda_i x_i}{1-\lambda_n}=$$

$$\lambda_nx_n+(1-\lambda_n)y_n$$

Comment: Hey thanks yea, sorry i forgot to say i got that part already sorry